# How to hook into woocommerce_after_checkout_validation depending on the AJAX JSON results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a custom input to the WooCommerce checkout form and it receives a JSON data from an URL. If the user's input, was valid, the received JSON will will have a `true` value, if not, it will have a `false` value in it.

I already did that using the AJAX JQuery function.

**What I want?**

When user clicks on the **Place order** button, besides other potential errors, I want to add a validation error to the WooCommerce if the received JSON data is `false`. If the user corrected the input and received `true` value from URL, when clicking on the Checkout button again, I want the error to be cleared.

How can I hook into `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` and add/remove validation errors on the fly with JS/JQuery? I added some comments to the code to make my problem a bit clearer.

```
//custom-wc-checkout.js
$(document).on("input", "#custom_input", function () {


console.log($(this).val());
  var value = $(this).val();
  var isValidCode = false;

  function checkCode(value, callback) {
    $.getJSON(
      "http://localhost/special/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/" + value,
      function (jsonData) {
        isValidCode = jsonData.content.protected;
        callback(isValidCode2);
      }
      );
    }

checkCode(value, function (isValidCode) {
  // Is it true or false
  console.log(isValidCode);

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/special/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        action: "validate_e_code",
        json: isValidCode,
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(response);
        json = data.json;
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("error");
      },
    });
  });  
});
```

PHP code:

```
//Ajax.php

$isValid = false;

function validate_e_code()
{
    global $isValid;
    $isValid = $_POST["json"];

    //Update: I tried to add a custom session as CBroe advised, 
    //but I don't know how to use the session to tell the WooCommerce 
    //update the validation results depending on the session value.

    WC()->session->set('the_field_name', $isValid);
    echo json_encode(WC()->session->get('the_field_name'));

    echo $isValid;
    die();
}

//$isValid remains false, even if the input code is valid and $_POST["json"]'s value is true
//So it always displays the error
if ($isValid == false) {
    add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_json', 10, 2);
}

function validate_json($fields, $errors)
{
    $errors->add('validation', 'Your code is not valid!');
}
```

PS I used the WordPress REST API for testing. It doesn't matter, only note that the JS code returns a `true` or `false` value, depending on what user enters in `#custom_input` (custom field) and then we pass the Boolean value to the `validate_e_code` PHP function.

Comment: There is no connection between your AJAX request that performs the validation, and the actual "place order" request. Unless you added your new field in a way that it gets send together with the rest of the data when the order it placed (so that you could simply perform the validation again, in your hook callback), you will have to store your validation result into a session.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, would you give a little more help? I took my time and tried many ways. I added (or I think I added) a custom session to the PHP function, `validate_e_code`. This: `WC()->session->set('the_field_name', $isValid);` `echo json_encode(WC()->session->get('the_field_name'));` Now I don't know how to use the session to tell the WooCommerce update the validation results depending on the session value.